# Use second or third (etc) row from fetched data to determine a variable

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I have data stored in a database.  This is the mysqli syntax.

```
SELECT naam, url, ext 
FROM img
WHERE naam LIKE 'Avatar%'
```

This is how I retrieve the first row

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE)  {   
$naam = $row['naam'];     $url = $row['url'];       $ext=['ext']; 
}

echo $naam;    echo $url;    echo $ext;
```

My target now is to determine a variable like for example $Jannick (the second row in the table) with info from the fetched mysqli data. 
- This means I can use the determined variable outside the while loop -

I can't figure out how, eventhough I have already tried several different fetch-options and for or foreach loops.

So far I can only determine $Wouter as 'Wouter' is the first row that is fetched.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you only want a specific row returned based on the `$Jannick` value?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment immediately. I am quite new to stackoverflow. Thank you for your time in the first place of course.

The $Jannick value is an example. I want to use determined variables outside the while loop that fetches the data.

Comment: BTW, in your code above, $naam  $url and  $ext will hold the LAST value from the database, not the first. This is because the values will be overwritten for each pass through the while loop.

Comment: You can try changing your SQL query : "SELECT naam, url, ext FROM img
WHERE naam LIKE 'Avatar%'  LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1;" This will get the second row from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first save all the rows in a 2-D array, and then simply fetch the row and the related data you want using indexes.

```
$f_data=array(); 
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($QueryResult))  {   
    $q_array['naam']=$row['naam'];  
    $q_array['url']=$row['url'];  
    $q_array['ext']=$row['ext'];
    array_push($f_data,$q_array);  
 }
```

And then the second row can be used like
`$res=$f_data[1]`

Also I would highly recommend to use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) OR [**MySQLi**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as `mysql`extensions are deprecated
. Here's how you would use PDO for this case,

```
$db= new PDO('mysql:host='.$dbserver.';dbname='.$dbname.'',$dbuser, $dbpwd);
$rs=$db->prepare($query);  \\prepared statements provide numerous advantages over normal statements check it out
$rs->execute();  

while($row=$rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))  
{  
   \\your code here
}
```

You can put the database connection, prepare and execute statements in a function ,usually in a different file for interactions with database, import it and call the function.

Comment: I think this is what I am searching for. I will try it and choose this as most suitable answer when I have it working. 

I already want to thank you for your time, and of course the given code!

Comment: well I hope you can make it work. I tried to be as helpful as possible.

Comment: Isn't it weird I need to make a new array out of an existing array? It works, but it remains somehow weird to me.

Comment: I have one question on your answer, if it is bothering and taking too much time I do not mind if you don't answer.

What does the $json_array exactly contain?

Comment: It's because this way makes it possible to select the columns you want from the returned row. You can push the the array `$row` straight-away too to the final array.

Comment: Oh I edited that . Please check it is actually `$q_array`  I used the snippet from something I had worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE)  {
```

To

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult))  { 
$naam = $row['naam'];     $url = $row['url'];       $ext=['ext']; 

echo $naam;    echo $url;    echo $ext;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you quick answer!

These will echo all values. But what I want is determine a variable and use it outside the while loop.

Comment: Can you post your exact mysqli syntax and other coding used ?

Comment: I can but it would make the total less overall clear I'm afraid